# Verb for asking nuisance questions

Tags: single-word-requests

(I hope this wouldn't count as a meta question). Is there a verb for asking nuisance questions?

I did check the list of previous questions suggested as possibly having my answer.

Otherwise this is my first step of research.

I'd settle for just being a nuisance. A verb for that, that is.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb for asking nuisance questions is "**pester**". One who asks nuisance questions can be called a **pest**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pester

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pest